# How can I loop through multiple dataframes, for a list of strings, search for columns containing string and create multiple new files?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 24 data files (`bsls`). Each file contains a fixed number of rows but a variable number of columns (`sites`). I have a clean list of 23 `sites` but cannot do an exact match as the column names pertaining to each site contains additional information.

I've read these files into `R` using the following code:

```
#list files from dir and read, skipping rows until 'Q Num'
temp <- list.files() # e.g. info-stuff-nameofbsl-otherStuff.csv

# read.xls and strip bsl name from file and assign as object name
for(i in temp){
    assign(unlist(strsplit(i, split = '-', fixed = T))[3],
           read.xls(i, pattern = "Q Num"))
}

#create list of dataframes (24 bsls)
bsls <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

#clean list of site names
sites <- ("NewYork","London","Sydney","Paris","Manchester","Angers","Venice","Bangkok","Glasgow","Boston","Perth","Canberra","Lyons","Washington","Milan","Cardiff","Dublin","Frankfurt","Ottawa","Toronto","El.Salvador","Taltal","Caldera")
```

**Example of the first 3 lines of 1 of the 24 `bsls` datasets**

e.g. the BSL1

```
QNum,   QuestionText,   % unrelatedCol, NewYork_Other_info, London_some_other_info, Venice_other_diff_info, 
q17a,   question?,                 74%,              69%,                     81%,                  76%,
q17b,   Another question?,         72%,              73%,                     77%,                  74%,
```

The outcome I need is for each of the 23 `sites` to have a `.csv` file containing all columns found within the 24 data files (`bsls`).

**My current attempt...**

```
for(site in sites){                             #for each site
    assign(site, data.frame())                  #create empty data frame to add vectors to
    for(bsl in dfs){                            #for each dataset
        if (grepl(site, colnames(bsl))){        #substring match
           next                                 #go back to for loop
        }
    assign(site$bsl, bsl[,grepl("site", colnames(bsl))]) #assign column to dataframe
    } 
}
```

**The solution would look like this...**

E.g London.csv

```
QNum,   QuestionText, BSLname1_Other_info,  BSLname2_some_other_info, BSL5other_diff_info, 
q17a,   question?,                 74%,              69%,                     81%,                  76%,
q17b,   Another question?,         72%,              73%,                     77%,                  74%,
```

There would be 23 files, one for each site, containing the columns pertaining to the site from the 24 input `bsl` files.

EDIT - worth stating that each of the `bsls` are not called `bsl1`, `bsl2`... etc but are in fact unique strings e.g. `unit`,`section`,`team`... etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code ended up solving my question. I first had to break the original question down further by renaming all of the columns in the `bsls` list of dataframes prior to the `for loop`. This was in order to know from which `bsl` the `site` belonged to - the renaming logic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882994/how-to-rename-all-columns-in-a-dataframe-to-include-the-name-of-the-data-for-all).

**The loop solution**

```
#this loop prints the files
for (site in sites){
    #create new file with question cols only
    newfile <- data.frame(NewYork[,1:2], stringsAsFactors = F)
    # search for columns in bsls relating to site
    for (bsl in bsls){
        colids <- grepl(site, colnames(bsl))
        cols <- bsl[,colids, drop = F]
        newfile <- cbind(newfile, cols)
        }
    filename <- paste0("Site ", site," .csv")
    write.xlsx(newfile, file = filename, row.names = F)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)


bind_rows(bsls, .id = bsl) %>%
  gather(variable, value, 
         matches(sites %>% paste(collapse = "|") ), 
         na.rm = TRUE ) %>%
  separate(variable, c("site", "new_variable", 
           sep = "_", extra = "merge") %>%
  unite(final_variable, bsl, new_variable, sep = "_") %>%
  spread(final_variable, value) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  do(write.csv(., paste("site", first(.$site), ".csv") ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt @bramtayl. A couple of points. `library(tidyr)` is needed for `gather`. `bind_rows(bsls)` doesn't work since the number of columns varies across each `bsl` dataset. I tried using `bind_cols(bsls)` which does bind, however, I need to know from which `bsl` dataset each column came from for the new `site` dataset. I.e. the columns need to contain the name of the `bsl` dataset it came from.

Comment: bind_rows should indeed work even if the number of columns varies. I've added the .id so that you should be able to retain bsls info. Also added the na.rm arg to gather.

Comment: `Error: object 'variable' not found`. Also, each site `Site` has a unique name e.g. `("NewYork", "London", "Sydney" .... etc)` so `starts_with("Site")` won't work. My apologies for this, I'll update the question to reflect the unique names.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that `BSLs` are also unique strings.

Comment: ok, edited to hopefully take care of the different site names. The names of the bsls list will end up in the variable names at the end, so just choose them to be whatever makes most sense.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. To clarify, when you say _'so just choose them to be whatever makes sense'_. I currently have a list of the dataframes `bsls` where each element is a dataframe with the name of the bsl. Could I just use the existing dataframe list `bsls` within your answer to name the columns? OR would it better if I created a list of strings containing the names of the `bsls` similar to the list for `sites`?

Comment: Now getting the following `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi) : names do not match previous names`.